# Use register_setting() in a loop

Tags: functions, theme-development, core

I try to use the function register_setting() in a loop but the settings are not set.

This is my code

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', function()
{
    $registerSettings = array 
    (
        'homepage_intro',
        'Color',
        'etc.'
    );
    
    foreach( $registerSettings as $registerSetting )
    {
        register_setting( 'habsj_option_group', $registerSetting );
    }
});
?>
```

Is there somebody who can help me with this?

Comment: Do you have any kind of callback functions where the values are/should be set?